# How to get user information and share score in Telegram gaming platform?

Tags: telegram-bot

I created a game bot in telegram.
I have some questions.

1. How to get user information in game
2. How to share user score in game
3. And What is parameters in telegram game bot url when it's opened ?

> Sorry for my bad english , I need help to edit my post to make it more correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you start the game, a callback query including the info is received by your web page (bot).
2. Use setGameScore from telegram API.

these links helped me

https://blog.ludei.com/how-to-adapt-html5-telegram/

https://blog.ludei.com/how-to-create-a-game-bot-and-publish-your-html5-games-on-telegram/